# How do I move data from one array to another? Using UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios6, nsmutablearray

Following on from my last question, I have a tableview populated with 2 NSMutableArrays, 2 sections and 2 section headers, all of which are working ok.

```
incompleteItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3"... , nil];

completeItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
```

I have set it up so that when a user swipes to the right, the cell accessory changes from disclosure to checkmark, and when swiping to the left changes from checkmark to disclosure. The gestures are achieved using handleSwipeLeft/Right methods.

What I'd like to do is when a user swipes to the right, the Item from the incompleteItems array is moved into the completedItems array, thus moving the item from the "Incomplete" section to the "Complete" section.

What would be the best way to achieve such a thing? My experience is limited so this is somewhat outside of my knowledge.

Any help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the object from one array to the other and then delete it immediately.

```
-(void)incompleteToCompleteAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [complete addObject:[incompleteItems objectAtIndex:index]];
    [incompleteItems removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

-(void)completeToIncompleteAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [incompleteItems addObject:[complete objectAtIndex:index]];
    [complete removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Since this will only occur as a result of a UI action I assume that this will happen on the main thread and there will be no reason for locking.

Comment: +1 this. You will also need to reload the tableview so the "rowForIndexPath" method (I think that's what it's called) gets called and the new object is returned.

You also have to consider moving the selected tableview row, which means a user must have one row selected first.

Comment: Thanks Joe, whilst the methods make perfect sense, I'm not sure how to put them in. I'm guessing I'd need to some how get the cell which has been swiped first? Or have I missed the point? :S

@dmoss18 Would that be [self.tableView reloadData] under cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a nice animation?  Check out: `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.  Make sure you wrap these calls with `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

I don't know of an easy way to animate moving a cell from one tableView to another.  I can imagine a method that requires you to do a 3-step animation manually, removing the cell (and adding it to a new view that floats in front of your whole view hierarchy), moving the new view to the destination location (you may need to do your own math to determine the screen coordinates of the destination) and finally an addition animation.  You could use a dummy cell that is completely transparent and swap it in / out in the first and last pieces of the animation to give the tableview something to hold the place of your transferred cell.